# Tkinter OptionMenu arguments

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I like to explicitly specify arguments. For example:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a+b
```

Anytime I call it I write:

```
func(a=6, b=7)
```

Instead of:

```
func(6, 7)
```

I can't do this with the `OptionMenu` class in Tkinter. The following example is within a custom class

```
self.var = tk.StringVav()
choices = ['op1', 'op2']
self.menu_m = tk.OptionMenu(master=self.frame_1, variable=self.var, *choices)
```

This results in multiple values for the argument 'master'. How can I explicitly define the master, variable, and list of options to use?

Comment: You might be missing an argument, `value = 'op1'`

Comment: It doesn't work when you even try this for `variable`: `variable = self.var` raises `TypeError`. And the body of the error says: `__init__() got multiple values for argument 'variable'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `OptionMenu` widget is somewhat poorly implemented. Regardless of your preferences, the optionmenu isn't designed to accept keyword arguments for the first three parameters `master`, `variable`, and `value`. They must be presented in that order as positional arguments.

```
self.menu_m = tk.OptionMenu(self.frame_1, self.var, *choices)
```

Comment: Why did you write `.., choices[0], *choices)` instead of just `..., *choices)`? Seems like the former would result in the first menu item appearing twice.

Comment: @martineau: I was apparently confused. Unfortunately, the tk and ttk OptionMenus are subtly different, and I must have been thinking of the ttk optionmenu at the time. The `ttk.OptionMenu` takes an additional keyword argument named `default` immediately after the positional arguments.   I'll fix the answer.